# SQLite where clause acting strange with TEXT fields

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, where-clause

I've searched up and down sqlite.org and can't figure this one out. I'm used to MySQL so I think maybe I am overlooking something.

See the following code:

```
sqlite> select id,event_number,must_say from events where id=28;
28|'28'|'AFK'
sqlite> select id,event_number,must_say from events where must_say='AFK';
sqlite> select id,event_number,must_say from events where must_say like 'AFK';
sqlite> select id,event_number,must_say from events where must_say like 'A%';
sqlite> select id,event_number,must_say from events where must_say=='AFK';
sqlite>
```

Needless to say, I really was expecting the following to be returned for ALL of the above queries, not just the first one:

```
28|'28'|'AFK'
```

I'm getting this behavior on all TEXT fields. It seems I can't search at all.

Here is the schema of my events table, with the irrelevant fields omitted:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    EVENT_NUMBER INTEGER,
    MUST_SAY TEXT
);
```

Any ideas? I just want to be able to search by arbitrary text fields in the table.

Edit: I'm using SQLite3.

Comment: It should work. Try to insert a new row and execute the query. Try also `like '%K%'`, maybe you have non printable characters.

Comment: You were right. I wasn't doing enough character stripping in my database population. Can I promote your comment to an answer somehow?

Comment: I don't think so but you can at least mark the comment as "great comment". I don't know if I should copy the comment as answer...

Comment: I'm still having trouble in a different table/field. I'm stripping all non-printable chars in my input. Is there a way to see non-printable chars in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also have whitespace in your columns.

You can see spaces with

```
select '|' || must_say || '|' from events
```

You can see unprintables with

```
select hex(must_say) from events
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! The problem was that I was inserting strings using single quotes and didn't realize the quotes were getting inserted into the fields.

Comment: A little more explanation would have been nice